# How to Assign back submit-success JSON response to the clicked event in the PHP loop. amp-form, amp-bind

Tags: amp-html, amp-bind, amp-form

on submit-success, form returns a JSON response and I am trying to add the response to the clicked  tag **[class]="wishstatus"** but it is getting added to all the  tag since it is in the PHP loop.
is there any solution to add the JSON response to the clicked  tag..?

**JSON Response**
{"message":"ADDED","type":2,"codez":"wishlistSelected"}

```
**AMP FORM**                    
    <form method="post" id="courseTap" action-xhr="" target="_top" on="submit-success: 
        AMP.setState({wishstatus: event.response.codez})">
     **PHP LOOP**
         for ($x = 0; $x <= 5;$x++) {
          <a href="..." [class]="wishstatus" on="tap:AMP.setState({datataptype: '1', 
          datatappost:'123'}),courseTap.submit">
          </a>
          }
           <input type="text" name="wtm"  [value]="datataptype" hidden>
           <input type="text" name="wcy"  [value]="datatappost" hidden>
                        <div submit-success>
                            <template type="amp-mustache">
                              {{message}} 
                           </template>
                        </div>
                        <div submit-error>
                           <template type="amp-mustache">
                             {{message}} 
                           </template>
                        </div>   
                 </form>
```